# Convert the binary number into base 2 scientific notation

Tags: c++, floating-point

Sorry, maybe my explanation is not understandable (edit).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3jHv.png)
in the figure, to shorten the number, we use scientific notation, but shouldn't we use
`a x 10^n`

however in the image, using
`a x 2^n`

why use base 2.
isn't it if we add base 10 the right answer

this is the result if i use
`a x 2^n`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMALS.png)
(it is not in accordance with)

this is the result if i use
`a x 10^n`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntGtC.png)

Thankyou for answer

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you're asking? Take a look at the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: It's exactly the same principle in binary as in decimal; 1.11 in base 10 is 1*10^0 + 1*10^-1 + 1*10^-2 (one and one tenth and one hundredth). In base 2, 1.11 is 1*2^0 + 1*2^-1 + 1*2^-2 (one and one half and one quarter- 1.75 in decimal notation). (The example is written in binary; in decimal, like in your calculator, 1.010101001 * 2^6 is 1.010101001 * 64. Writing a number with only zeros and ones does not make it a binary number.)

Answer (score 1):

In base 10, 1.010101001d x 10d^6 = 1010101.001d

In base 2, 1.010101001b x 10b^6 = 1010101.001b (but 10b = 2d)